# Email Server on Amazon EC2

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, postfix, email-server

We have an email server running postfix on AWS m1.medium instance. We push out roughly 150,000 emails a week (30,000 emails a day). We do not want to use Amazon SES for some business reasons. It usually takes more than 2 hours for each day's send and we want to reduce this. What suggestions do you have in terms of increasing the AWS instance type / class? There is a number of instance classes and we cannot figure out which class / type would be ideal for our situation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I help send millions of emails every day from my employer.

I'm not sure the problem is solved by adjusting your instance size.

What is your bottleneck?  Do you have dedicated IPs from AWS for sending email?  Have you asked Amazon to add reverse DNS for your sending IPs?  Are the major MBP (MailBox Providers) limiting your sends?  Have you signed up for their FBLs (FeedBack Loops)?  Do you have a bounce email processing system?

Some people don't know how to unsubscribe and some don't trust the links in the email.  This is why it is important to have the FBLs.  There are also headers you can add in the emails to help people unsubscribe.

I look forward to your reply.